# Aggregate multiple inner joins result into json tree hierarchy

Tags: postgresql

I have five tables that are interconnected with each other using junction tables:

[image]

When I execute this query to get all posts with all comments of all users:

```
select
    "user".full_name,
    "post".text,
    "comment".text
from "user"
    inner join "user_post" on "user"."id" = "user_post"."user_id"
    inner join "post" on "user_post"."post_id" = "post"."id"
    inner join "post_comment" on "post".id = post_comment.post_id
    inner join "comment" on "post_comment".comment_id = comment.id;
```

I get this result:

[image]

As you can see I don't have a desirable tree based structure. How do I now group all of this data into correct tree-based structure user -> post -> comment using postgresql? Is it even should be done inside postgresql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned JSON in your question title, you can use [json functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) and [json aggregates](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) to build the tree structure in Postgres, using [subqueries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-SCALAR-SUBQUERIES):

```
SELECT
    "user".full_name,
    (SELECT
        json_agg(json_build_object(
            'text', post.text,
            'comments', (
                SELECT json_agg(json_build_object(
                    'text', comment.text,
                    'author_names', (
                         SELECT json_agg(
                             author.full_name
                         )
                         FROM "user" AS author
                         JOIN user_comment uc ON author.id = uc.user_id AND uc.is_author
                         WHERE uc.comment_id = comment.id
                    )
                ))
                FROM comment
                JOIN post_comment pc ON comment.id = pc.comment_id
                WHERE pc.post_id = post.id
            )
        ))
        FROM post
        JOIN user_post up ON post.id = up.post_id
        WHERE up.user_id = "user".id
          AND up.is_author
    ) AS authored_posts
FROM "user";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It looks really scary though, I hoped that SQL had some simpler syntax, for such use cases :(

Comment: It's not that scary, the structure is rather predictable. I also added one more layer (comment authors) than requested in your question to further demonstrate the common structure :-) And the joins would not be necessary if each post/comment had only a single author and each comment would belong to only a single post.